# ReactJS - passing data from a child component to its parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following structure of components in the application:

```
class Car extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cars: [],
            ...
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/cars')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({cars: response.data});
                console.log('cars: ', cars);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('CAUGHT IT! -> ', err);
            });
    }
    render() {
      return (
        ...
        <CarAddNew />
        <CarSearch />
        <CarList cars={this.state.cars} />
      )
    }
}
```

and then

```
export default class CarSearch extends Component {
    constructor(){...}
    handleSearchSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ..
        axios.post('/api/cars/search', searchCars)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('response.data: ', response.data);
            })
    }
    render() {
        return(
          ... search form ...
        )
    }
```

When I search data in the database through the `CarSearch` component, it will fetch and load the right data, that's great. However, how do I pass this "new" found data to the `CarList` component, so I can display the on the page?

Comment: Well, you can pass data from```<Carlist newData={this.state.newDate}``` from your ```CarSearch``` component and then in your ```CarList``` component use ```PropTypes```to declare the static property that you want to receive.

Comment: So... I would be passing it like twice? From `Cars` to `CarList` and `CarSearch`?

Comment: Not, you have a ```CarList``` component I suppose that is to render a list of Cars so If you have a ```CarList``` to render cars you just need to pass data to ```CarList``` component. When you call the ```CarList``` component in ```CarSearch``` component pass the date found.

Comment: Apart from your question, do not try to `console.log` your state right after updating it. `setState` is asynchronous, so it is no healthy using a `console.log` like that. There is a callback option for `setState` but you can always log your state in the `render` method easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is the following:

```
class Car extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cars: [],
            ...
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/cars')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({cars: response.data});
                console.log('cars: ', cars);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('CAUGHT IT! -> ', err);
            });
    }
    handleSearch = () => {
        axios.post('/api/cars/search', searchCars)  // not sure where you are getting searchCars from, but you should get the idea
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({cars: response.data})
                console.log('response.data: ', response.data);
            })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        ...
        <CarAddNew />
        <CarSearch onSearch={this.handleSearch} />
        <CarList cars={this.state.cars} />
      )
    }
}


export default class CarSearch extends Component {
    constructor(){...}
    handleSearchSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSearch() // I'm assuming you probably want to pass something here
    }
    render() {
        return(
          ... search form ...
        )
    }
```

Comment: I liked this approach. Cleaner, more pure child.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - just wondering - in the search form, I want to have the button text "Search" when before searching or after searching the data and "Searching..." during searching the database. I wanted to add a state variable to the `CarSearch ` component for this purpose, but I am confused how do I detect this activity when the `onSearch()` is in a different component. Thank you!

Comment: you could keep the state for that in the Car component, then pass it to props of the CarSearch component.
Something like:
this.state = { isSearching: false }
Then in handleSearch:
this.setState({ isSearching: true })
once you get the search results, then switch it back to false.
<CarSearch isSearching={this.state.isSearching} />

Answer (score 2):

One option is to propagate the data up through a prop on `CarSearch`. Consider the (truncated) example...

```
handleSearchSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios.post('/api/cars/search', searchCars).then(response => {
    this.props.onData(response.data);
  });
}
```

where, `onData` calls back up to the following (then later setting state)...

```
constructor() {
  // [...]
  this.onSearchResult = this.onSearchResult.bind(this);
}

onSearchResult(cars) {
  this.setState({cars}); // results from CarSearch
}

render() {
  return (
    <CarAddNew />
    <CarSearch 
      onData={this.onSearchResult} />
    <CarList 
      cars={this.state.cars} />
  )
}
```

Comment: While both our answers are basically the same, your answer is creating a new function every time render is called, since you are binding in render.  You should at least be binding in the constructor.

Comment: While slightly gaining performance by binding at construction is worthwhile to consider, your answer isn't the same - you bring the child functionality into the parent component. The question asks how to emit a child component function result up to a parent, and broadcast the data back down to a neighboring sibling component. I will edit for the micro-optimization.